# SQL count votes in one table include name from another table

Tags: sql

I have one table that is used for voting. What I have so far:

```
SELECT VotedFor, count(*) As Winners
FROM Vote
GROUP BY VotedFor
ORDER BY count(*) DESC;
```

Gives me the top winners

Now I need to add the name of the guy they voted for from another table
The only thing in common is an ID field in both tables but one is text and the other is an auto number.

Using Access. (What I have, second what I need)

```
VotedFor  Winner
  3         99
  1         54

VotedFor  Winner  Name
  3         99    Fred
  1         54    Barnie
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
SELECT VotedFor, count(*) As Winners, P.Name
FROM Vote inner join PersonNames as P
on Vote.VotedFor = P.ID
GROUP BY VotedFor, P.Name
ORDER BY count(*) DESC;
```

Comment: Getting 'Type mismatch on Expression' I think because Vote.VoterFor is text and P.ID is auto number (long integer): using access

Comment: I got it now, I just add a Cint(Vote.VoteFor):

Comment: SELECT VotedFor, count(*) AS Winners, P.LastName
FROM Vote INNER JOIN Entries AS P ON Cint(Vote.VotedFor) = P.ID
GROUP BY VotedFor, P.LastName
ORDER BY count(*) DESC;